# Meteor+angular2. Errno 3221225477 elifecycle

Tags: angular, meteor

I try do production of my meteor project, but have elifecycle error with status 3221225477. Start of project is succeses, but I can't build and production it.

I using Meteor 1.6.0.1 and Node v8.2.1.

I think that problem in angular2, but I don't understand why. My OS is Windows 7

The major error is : err! code ELIFECYCLE

[image: console error]

Packages:

```
     "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "5.0.5",
      "@angular/cdk": "5.0.0-rc0",
      "@angular/common": "5.0.5",
      "@angular/compiler": "5.0.5",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.5",
      "@angular/core": "5.0.5",
      "@angular/forms": "5.0.5",
      "@angular/http": "5.0.5",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.5",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.5",
      "@angular/router": "5.0.5",
      "@types/meteor": "1.4.12",
      "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "^0.2.0",
      "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
      "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
      "buffer": "^5.0.8",
      "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
      "core-js": "^2.5.1",
      "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.1",
      "meteor-node-stubs": "0.3.2",
      "meteor-rxjs": "0.4.8",
      "mongodb": "^2.2.34",
      "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
      "request": "^2.82.0",
      "rxjs": "5.5.2",
      "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
      "typescript": "2.6.2",
      "typings": "^2.1.1",
      "xmldoc": "^1.1.0",
      "zone.js": "0.8.18"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
      "chai": "4.1.2"
     }

tsconfig.json

    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
"target": "es6",
"noImplicitAny": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"pretty": true,
"noEmitHelpers": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

logs

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'prod' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.2.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'preprod', 'prod', 'postprod' ]
5 info lifecycle auth-insysbio@~preprod: auth-insysbio@
6 info lifecycle auth-insysbio@~prod: auth-insysbio@
7 verbose lifecycle auth-insysbio@~prod: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle auth-insysbio@~prod: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\tkachenko\Documents\GitHub\auth-insysbio\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\condor\bin\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\tkachenko\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\tkachenko\AppData\Local\.meteor\;C:\Users\tkachenko\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\tkachenko\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
9 verbose lifecycle auth-insysbio@~prod: CWD: C:\Users\tkachenko\Documents\GitHub\auth-insysbio
10 silly lifecycle auth-insysbio@~prod: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   '' ]
11 silly lifecycle auth-insysbio@~prod: Returned: code: 3221225477  signal: null
12 info lifecycle auth-insysbio@~prod: Failed to exec prod script
13 verbose stack Error: auth-insysbio@ prod: ``
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:289:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:921:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid auth-insysbio@
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\tkachenko\Documents\GitHub\auth-insysbio
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "prod"
18 verbose node v8.2.1
19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225477
22 error auth-insysbio@ prod: ``
22 error Exit status 3221225477
23 error Failed at the auth-insysbio@ prod script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225477, true ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: I get this error constantly ever since a recent meteor update (1.6.1 I think it was), in dev.  It happens randomly, forcing me to restart the server.    No angular here, just blaze.